# What could be causing this error?

Tags: payment-gateways

I am facing an error in Drupal 9 Stripe module. After installing the module and setting the private and public keys, I visited the /admin/commerce/orders/84/payments/add page, and selected my newly created 'test stripe payment' as payment gateway. Then, I selected one of the payment methods that I've added from /user/18/payment-methods (*Add new payment method*). This redirected me to the *Add payment* page where there is an *Amount* field and two radio buttons (*Authorize only* and *Authorize and capture*) and an *Add payment* button. When I click on this button, the site crashes with the following error.

> Error : Call to a member function getRemoteId() on null dans Drupal\commerce_stripe\Plugin\Commerce\PaymentGateway\Stripe->createPaymentIntent() (/home/mywebsite/www/web/modules/contrib/commerce_stripe/src/Plugin/Commerce/PaymentGateway/Stripe.php line 430)

The line causing the error belongs to this function. Does it mean `$payment_method` is null? Do you have any idea on what might be causing this error?

```php
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
public function createPaymentIntent(OrderInterface $order, $capture = TRUE) {
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_payment\Entity\PaymentMethodInterface $payment_method */
  $payment_method = $order->get('payment_method')->entity;

  // Line 430
  $payment_method_remote_id = $payment_method->getRemoteId();
  $customer_remote_id = $this->getRemoteCustomerId($order->getCustomer());

  $amount = $this->toMinorUnits($order->getTotalPrice());
  $order_id = $order->id();
  $capture_method = $capture ? 'automatic' : 'manual';
  $intent_array = [
    'amount' => $amount,
    'currency' => strtolower($order->getTotalPrice()->getCurrencyCode()),
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'metadata' => [
      'order_id' => $order_id,
      'store_id' => $order->getStoreId(),
    ],
    'payment_method' => $payment_method_remote_id,
    'capture_method' => $capture_method,
  ];
  if (!empty($customer_remote_id)) {
    $intent_array['customer'] = $customer_remote_id;
  }
  try {
    $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create($intent_array);
    $order->setData('stripe_intent', $intent->id)->save();
  }
  catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
    ErrorHelper::handleException($e);
  }
  return $intent;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using **Commerce Stripe**, not **Stripe**.  Please link to the module you are using so that your question is understandable.

Comment: Hello , thank you for your comment @PatrickKenny , I have installed all of these : Stripe, Stripe examples, Commerce Stripe, Commerce Stripe - payment request button and I set the oublic and preivate keys for stripe here /admin/config/stripe.

Comment: You don't need both the Stripe and the Commerce Stripe modules; you should pick one or the other because they do similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce Stripe is a bit of a mess at the moment.  There are lots of issues that need to be fixed as you can see in the [project issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_stripe?categories=All).

You are probably experiencing the bug described on [Stripe\PaymentIntent instance has invalid ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3108793), but there is a longer discussion about how to handle this at [[meta] SCA, the Stripe Review pane and recurring payments](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3171424).

Basically, the issue is that Commerce Stripe does not generate a payment ID unless you go through the review pane first.  That means that if you configure a standard Commerce checkout flow and go through that flow (login -> cart -> checkout, etc.), then the module will probably work.  If not, you will spend hours searching the issue queue to try to debug the module.

Source: Have spent several frustrated hours over the past couple years with Commerce Stripe.

If it helps, I'm currently using the following patches just to get the module to work on my site:

```
    "drupal/commerce_stripe": {
        "do not load stripe library on every page": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-03/3083393-21.patch",
        "skip review step by autosubmit": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-09-16/commerce_stripe-3171411-2.patch",
        "fix 1112 errors https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3177168": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-10-16/3177168-2_commerce_stripe-fix_address_errors.patch",
        "fix TrustedCallbackInterface warning https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3168822": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-10-09/PaymentMethodAddForm%20needs%20to%20implement%20TrustedCallbackInterface%20for%20Drupal%209-3168822-14.patch"
    },
```

Comment: thank you so much for this detailled answer ! can you give me a link or screenshot just to know how can i configure and set a new flow ?? and if I desactivate commerce stripe and keep stripe only, could that solve the issue ?

Comment: I have two workflows here : /admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows , 
Commerce Stripe - payment request button and a default one . so i should create a third one ? if yes how to set it as default?

Comment: I tried to create a new worklfow they let me  choose between two plugins Multistep - Default or Commerce Stripe payment request button Flow . If i choose the first one , i desactivated the review steps but still have same prob

Comment: @jane [Commerce Checkout flow docs](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/checkout/configure-checkout)

Comment: I went to this link and created a new workflow with everything but the review step.
Then i went to configure the default order type and I selected the checkout flow that i created but there is another field which is workflow, that can be default, fulfillment with validation ..  I tried them but nothing works.

Comment: @jane You **must** have the review step, it's not optional.

Comment: Ok so it think my issue is that  i had the review step in the initial workflow but i didn't go through it because i was adding a payment directly to the order as described in my question. Now my question is how ken i go through this process normally? i don't know how to  access the review page for example, .. is there any link that helps me go through the process? For now i just created products in commerce and some orders manually, i don't have pages or nodes associated with products.

Comment: i went to /cart and proceeded and everything worked !!!!!! Thank You !!! So I can't just add a payment in the Back office ! each time i have to go though it all !! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and struggle to know what actions go on what steps.  These posts helped but had a lot of trial and error left to do. I thought I would post my flow for reference for others. Please note that a couple actions are custom modules that I built: (Terms and COnditions, and Need Help)

[image]